# How can I update the state of the class instance after Sidekiq has completed executing job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, sidekiq

I have this method in my model and want to update the `scheduled` state to `sent` once Sidekiq is done with the job.

```
def deliver_message_and_update_state
    if email_scheduled_at?
      SendMessageWorker.perform_at(email_scheduled_at, id)
      self.update(state: "scheduled")
    else
      SendMessageWorker.perform_async(id)
      self.update(state: "sent")
    end
end
```

Comment: You have to write code that updates state inside the worker.

Comment: I guess you call this method in an `after` hook.

Please post your sidekiq `worker` or `job` class. In there you call your `Message` class (or whatever it's called) and update the instance state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sidekiq worker doesn't know about the current model instance. So, You have to update the state in the end of worker i.e after the implementation of your code in the worker.

In your model

```
def deliver_message_and_update_state
  self.update(state: "scheduled")
  SendMessageWorker.perform_in(self.email_scheduled_at, self.id)
end
```

In your worker

```
class SendMessageWorker
  def perform(id)
  <Your code>
  YourModel.find(id).update(state: "sent")
  end
end
```